# Rewrite URL using sed while maintaining filename

Tags: regex, sed

I would like to find all instances of a URL in a file and replace them with a different link structure.

An example would be convert `http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Security_Panda.png` to `/images/Security_Panda.png`.

I am able to identify the link using a regular expression such as:

`^(http:)|([/|.|\w|\s])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)`

but need to rewrite using `sed` so that the file name is maintained. I understand that I will need to use `s/${PATTERN}/${REPLACEMENT}/g`.

Tried: `sed -i 's#(http:)|([/|.|\w|\s])*\.(?:jpg|gif|png)#/dir/$1#g' test` without success? Thoughts on how to improve the approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In basic sed, you need to escape the `()` symbols like `\(..\)` to mean a capturing group.

```
sed 's~http://[.a-zA-Z0-9_/-]*\/\(\w\+\.\(jpg\|gif\|png\)\)~/images/\1~g' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Security_Panda.png' | sed 's~http://[.a-zA-Z0-9_/-]*\/\(\w\+\.\(jpg\|gif\|png\)\)~/images/\1~g'
/images/Security_Panda.png
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
sed 's~^.*/\([^/]\{1,\}\)$~/images/\1~' file
/images/Security_Panda.png
```

**Testing:**

```
s='http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Security_Panda.png'
sed 's~^.*/\([^/]\{1,\}\)$~/images/\1~' <<< "$s"
/images/Security_Panda.png
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier way if you change your idea.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

URL="http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Security_Panda.png"
echo "/image/${URL##*/}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

command line

```
sed 's#^http:.*/\(.*\).$#/images/\1#g'
```

Example

```
 echo "http://www.domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Security_Panda.png "|sed 's#^http:.*/\(.*\).$#/images/\1#g'
```

results

```
/images/Security_Panda.png
```

Comment: This will modify all `http` url, and not only the images link `jpg|gif|png`

Answer (score 0):

An `awk` version:

```
awk -F\/  '/(jpg|gif|png) *$/ {print "/images/"$NF}' file
/images/Security_Panda.png
```